# make_graph Error in R

Tags: r, mapper

I use Version 0.98.1091 – © 2009-2014 RStudio, Inc. on my mac laptop. And as I was trying to run the function 'make_graph' from the 'igraph' package, it game me an error.
Here is how I installed the package,

> install.packages("igraph")
> library("igraph")

This part was fine, the following line was what gave me an error

> g1 <- make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6), directed = FALSE)
>
> Error: could not find function "make_graph"

Here is how I installed the igraph packages

> install.packages("igraph")
>
> Installing package into ‘/Users/besib/Library/R/3.1/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later: binary source igraph 0.7.1 1.0.1 trying URL 'cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1/igraph_0.7.1.tgz'; Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4816996 bytes (4.6 Mb) opened URL ================================================== downloaded 4.6 Mb

Here is what I got from sessonsInfo()

> sessionInfo()
>
> R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit) locale: [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 attached base packages:
>
> [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.1.2

Could someone help me fix this error? Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of `igraph` did you load? Look at the results of `sessionInfo()` (Packages have different versions than Rstuido)

Comment: Here is how I installed the igraph packages                                                   > install.packages("igraph")
Installing package into ‘/Users/besib/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source
  version is later:
       binary source
igraph  0.7.1  1.0.1

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1/igraph_0.7.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4816996 bytes (4.6 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 Mb

Comment: Here is what I got from sessonsInfo()> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
>

Comment: That `library(igraph)` command didn't run. Igraph is not listed as an attached package in the session info. Also, it's better to edit your question to include this info rather than putting in comments to it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick.